# When we can say "I am begin"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs, idioms, expressions

It's known that we can't say "I am begin" in English because it's gramitically wrong but someone told me that there are some cases where we can use it can anyone tell me what is this cases?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Otherwise, I cannot begin to understand what you mean. In any case: "I am begin" is not grammatical in English.  You might want to look up: verbs in the present continuous.

Comment: I agree with Lambie.  "I am begin" is not normally a grammatical sentence.  Please tell us what you would like to say, or why you think this is grammatical English.  Otherwise, this question will be closed for lack of detail.

Comment: I don't think putting anything after "I am begin" will make a grammatical sentence. However, you could say "I am Begin," using Begin as a name.

Comment: A performer asks: "Are you the stage manager? Can I begin my act?" To which the reply is "I am, begin".

Comment: @Weather That really should be "I am. Begin." So I don't think that qualifies.

Comment: @MattS - A semi-colon could be used: "I am; begin." And of course it qualifies.

Comment: Do you mean "I am beginning"? This is grammatical and colloquial English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I am begin" as punctuated here is simply ungrammatical.  There are two ways that it could be used correctly, however.  The first is that changing the punctuation can make it grammatical again.

> I am, begin.
>
> I am Begin.

Both of the above examples work.  In the first, you are answering a question, presumably "Are you ready?" by saying "(Yes) I am, (let's/you may) begin."  In the second, you are declaring that your name is literally "Begin", simply by capitalizing the B.

There is one other case in which "I am begin" is acceptable, and that is in poetry.  Poetry can stretch, bend, and break typical grammar in very creative ways-- but be careful.  Altering grammar for the sake of poetry requires intimate knowledge with English grammar and usage in order to make surprising associations and connections with more proper forms.  Without this knowledge, you may wind up not making enough connections, and thus writing nonsense that no one can read or understand, or make the *wrong* connections, and thus miscommunicate your intended message.